# File Sync with FTP Server

Tags: php, ftp, web-deployment

I have a Website with an FTP Server in BigRock.com. What my issue is, whenever there is a deployment, i will have to manually search and find all the files that need to be changed. Now the project is getting larger and larger and making these kind of changes is taking a lot of my valuable time.

So is there any Software/Tools available for Syncing with the FTP Server and changing files based on changes made locally? I am not sure about FileZilla Client since i couldn't find much options in it. I am pretty sure that there would be some solution for this. My project is done in Zend Framework with Doctrine ORM and Many other Libraries.

Comment: have you considered setting up a repository like cvs or svn?

Comment: You seriously need to evaluate Versioning Control Systems. Git (http://git-scm.com/) is a fantastic start!

Comment: I am using Assembla SVN. But the deployment server is bigrock.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try **[Allway Sync](http://allwaysync.com/)**

It uses innovative synchronization algorithms to synchronize your data between desktop PCs, laptops, USB drives, remote FTP/SFTP servers, different online data storages and more. Encrypted archives are supported. Allway Sync combines bulletproof reliability with extremely easy-to-use interface.

url http://allwaysync.com/

I tried personally is working fine for ftp and local file sync. and also it is free..

Comment: Does this Software Create any dummy files as Microsoft Sync Toy?

Comment: @Vijay Sarin, it will not create any dumy files. it will simply sync the files which are there in folder or drive.

Comment: I installed it and found a folder something like _SYNCDATA hidden in the folders i selected...!

Comment: hey, i got a work around from Assembla. Check the answer i posted. This is much simpler than i thought. But your mentioned software helped me with the sync to keep backup copies of my project in Different Machines and Different Disks on the same Machine.

Answer (score 4):

If you need a one-way synchronization from local files to server, you can check this free tool: http://sourceforge.net/p/phpfilesync/wiki/Home/

It could not be much easier to install or use.

Answer (score 0):

Working with Assembla, i found the FTP Tool in it.

Here is the reference link,

http://blog.assembla.com/assemblablog/tabid/12618/bid/78103/Deploying-a-Web-site-is-easy-with-Assembla-s-FTP-tool-Video.aspx

Its Easy to Work Out,

1. Add the FTP tool using the Tools section of your Admin tab.
2. Deploy code to any server with ftp or sftp installed.
3. Set the deploy frequency to manual (you push a button) or schedule automatic deployments for every commit, hourly, daily, or weekly.
4. Only changed files are deployed for fast and accurate deployments.
5. Easily roll back and deploy prior revisions.
6. Add multiple servers for staging and production releases or simply to deploy different repository directories to different locations.